# public key is not available http://mirror.ppa.trinitydesktop.org

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

Getting the **"because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 96C95152F5CFC95C"** for *mirror.ppa.trinitydesktop.org*

Tried several suggestion but they did NOT work.

**How do I install a public key for mirror.ppa.trinitydesktop.org?**

Comment: Which suggestions did you try?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.trinitydesktop.org/Ubuntu_Trinity_Repository_Installation_Instructions

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net --recv-keys F5CFC95C
```

After that:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install kubuntu-default-settings-trinity kubuntu-desktop-trinity
```

Comment: Terminal does NOT recognize "aptitude"

Comment: Replace aptitude with apt-get